# Ship wake modeling and definite integrals

Tags: numerical-methods, definite-integrals

In the study of the ship's wake, it needs to calculate the following definite integral:
$$z(\rho,\phi)=\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}d\theta\cos\left[\rho\cos\left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{\cos(\theta)^2}\right)\right]$$
Because it's impossible to calculate the indefinite integral of the integrand, I tried to calculate it using the Simpson rule. Obviously, in the points $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, the function is singular. Is there any method useful to avoid the problem of singularities? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with the problem of singularities, you can first try approaching the integral with a limit like an improper integral to obtain an analytic solution. If that doesn't work their are several numerical methods designed singularities. Some of them can be found here,

http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/p012061.pdf

This first thing I would suggest us reducing the order of the singularity by using a half angle identity on cos(θ)^2. Then the order of the singularity is 1/r instead of 1/r^2. Their are special Gauss Legendre integration schemes designed for singularities. For more information you can also look at the boundary element method. In this method a lot of integrals have singularities similar to your integral. Hope this helps.